# textColor attribute doesn't work on Android 6

Tags: android, android-text-color

In my application
AndoidManifest.xml

```
<application 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> 
<item name="android:textColor">#0A0B0A</item> 
</style>
```

When I start my application on real device with Android 6 I see White Colored text in my TextView. The TexView doesn't have any style or android:textColor attributes. whats the problem? on virtual device with Android 4 it works correctly (the text color is Black)

sorry for my language

Comment: have you tried clean build and restart of android studio?

Comment: can you be more specific, are you trying to change the color of text or ??

Comment: I'm trying that  the text in my TextView will be black (#0A0B0A) colored.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116633/androidtextcolor-no-longer-works-in-marshmallow

This one says, it should work on Marshmallow too

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

**res/values/colors:** 
create a color tag and add your color value and the name of that color

`<color name="text_color">#0A0B0A</color>`

Use this inTextView as

```
<TextView
 ....
android:textColor="@color/text_color"/>
```

For universal edit of textColor

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">#0A0B0A</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It will be work, but this way I shoud add this tag textColor to each TextView, EditText, etc . It's not good.

Comment: I have to use a one of AppCompat theme (imported library requers)